# csquotes: spacing between text guillemets

Tags: fonts, spacing, csquotes

Consider the following mwe:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

    \foreignquote{french}{lipsum}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Is there an easy way to reduce the spacing between the text and the guillemets?

Note: The idea is to use `\foreignquote{french}{...}` to typeset
[UML strereotypes](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile-diagrams.html#stereotype).

#### update

`\enquote{lipsum}` looks ok:

[image]

BTW: I'm using the guillemets to typeset [UML strereotypes](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile-diagrams.html#stereotype), it is not about French typography.

Comment: @sergej Then don't use `csquotes`. `\newcommand*\stereotype[1]{«#1»}`

Comment: @Manuel Makes sense. However, I'm using `\enquote` all over the place in my document and it felt obvious to use `csquotes` for stereotypes as well.

Comment: The fact that a quote has a syntax similar to your stereotypes has nothing to do with it. `csquotes` is for quotes; you are not quoting but using a particular syntax: define your own command.

Comment: I guess you're right, but grrr... ;)

Comment: French typography wants a space after « and one before » and apparently this is what `csquotes` implements. I endorse Manuel's opinion that `csquotes` is not the right tool for your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't try to use `csquotes` for something it isn't necessary, nor designed, nor useful. The fact that your syntax has `«»` doesn't mean it has anything to do with quotes.

```
\newcommand*\stereotype[1]{«#1»}
```